# Text-to-Speech Going too fast

Tags: text-to-speech

I have recently installed [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.svox.langpack.installer) into my Samsung Galaxy Y mobile phone running on Android 2.3 Gingerbread.

The speed at which words are being spoken by this system is too high for me to grasp. Also, I suspect that there is absolutely no pauses after commas and full stops.

I am not able to find any settings too. What should I do? Is this problem solvable?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Samsung GB, but on my Galaxy S3 running JB 4.1, the setting for the TTS speech rate is found in Settings -> Language and Input -> Text-to-speech Output -> Speech Rate.

Wbogacz suggests that setting may also be found at Settings -> Accessibility -> Text-to-speech Output -> Speech Rate

Comment: An additional location to look is Settings -> Accessibility -> Text-to-speech Output -> Speech Rate. When mine is enabled this way, you can listen to a sample to ascertain you are comfortable with the speech rate.